# Model velocity as function of distance in object subject to drag and propulsion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, rocket-science

Given an initial speed $v_0$ and acceleration $\frac{dv}{dt}|_0=a_0$, I need to find velocity as a function of distance knowing that

1. Drag is $ D = Av² $
2. Propulsion is $P = Bv + C$

I already found $v(t)$ and $S(t)$ by solving the non-linear ODE $$Av^2 -Bv - C +m \frac{dv}{dt} = 0$$ but the model that I need can't have time as a variable.

Is it possible to find $v(S)$ given the conditions above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible analytically. You need to solve for time in velocity equation and then plug it back into the distance equation. This way you are eliminating time between two equations.

Comment: I tried solving for time in the distance equation and plugging it back on the velocity equation. The problem is that the distance equation is something of the form s(t) = K* ln(cos(f(t)))+at and I can't solve for time...

Comment: No, don't do it that way. As I told you, use, velocity equation to solve for t which is doable. Then use that t inside the distance equation.

Comment: Do you have the relation for velocity equation independently (without differentiating distance) ?

Comment: I will try to do that. But that way I will end up with space as a function of velocity, no?
My final goal is to find the maximum velocity the object reaches in a given distance, that's why I thought I needed v(S) instead of S(v).

Comment: Once you have S(v) then you can invert the equation if possible numerically.

Comment: Ok. I think I'll need to do it numerically, don't think it's possible to invert it analytically.

Thank you, Benjamin!

Comment: @MFCic If you're willing to do things numerically then you may as well just solve your ODE numerically, e.g. using the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), [Verlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration), [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), etc

Comment: @lemon If I solve the ODE numerically I think I'll be adding avoidable errors in my model. If I can do it analytically, isn't it better to have the exact solution rather than an approximation due to numerical error?

Comment: @MFCic If you're doing *any* part of the evaluation numerically then you're introducing errors. I've posted an answer showing you how to solve this using the Euler method; note the emphasis that you can achieve arbitrary precision by decreasing the time-step.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much easier to solve the ODE numerically. The simplest method is that of Euler - here is some pseudocode:

```
s=distance to evaluate
x=0
v=v0
dt=0.01
while x < s
    dv_dt=(C+B*v-A*v*v)/m
    x=x+v*dt
    v=v+dv_dt*dt
return v
```

By decreasing the time-step `dt` you can achieve *arbitrary precision*. However, if, for some reason, you need to perform this calculation very quickly (e.g. because you need to repeat it billions of times) then you can do so faster with methods like Verlet or Runge-Kutta.

I should also add that there are optimisations you could make: for instance, you could store `v` and `x` as a function of `t` and fit curves (e.g. splines) to improve precision with very little computational overhead.